# to $routeProvider or $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been looking for a sound answer to to this dilema, to routeProvider or not to.

It appears as if $routeProvider is soon going to be discontinued and replace with $stateProvider unfortunately I don't know the accuracy of this statement plus stateProvider is still only available via ui_router plugin.

Is the plan to add stateProvider as part of the AngularJS Core? Is it save to assume that it will soon replace the old $routeProvider?

They certainly don't play well together and the migration CI that I found in github doesn't work and lacks documentation.

Comment: Were you looking for a more specific answer?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After a very long time we decided to bite the bullet and migrate from 1.1.1 to 1.2. At the same time we realized how limited $routerProvider really is so we went with ui-router. So far, we love it, it allows you to do some complex nesting in the views plus add a bit more structure to your app, for example, in $stateProvider you can define onEnter and onExit which allows you to modify your data and restore it upon exiting, you can also transitionTo state which is extremely powerful. I would vote for ui-router to be part of Angular core and even replace $routeProvider. I hope this helps you made up your mind. $routeProvider still works, if you have a basic app or demo page.

Comment: any idea if ui-router will make it to angular core?

Comment: There are definitely great plans for improvements in the core router in 2.0  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I3UC0RrgCh9CKrLxeE4sxwmNSBl3oSXQGt9g3KZnTJI/edit

Comment: Warning! $stateProvider is still in ACTIVE development, be sure you read the changes when the next version of angular.js is out and view the changes on it

Answer (score 10):

We started with $routeProvider and moved to $stateProvider to leverage some of the features that ui-router provides. When we moved the migration was absolutely trivial. Having said that, ui-router is still very early (from their [GitHub page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)):

> Warning: UI-Router is pre-beta and under active development. As such, while this library is well-tested, the API is subject to change. Using it in a project that requires guaranteed stability is not recommended.

Stick with $routeProvider until you decide you need something else. Until then, make sure you are getting good test coverage so that shifts like that aren't too big of a concern.